# How to import icons from multiple files in react native vector icons?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

If I wanted to use Ionicons and MaterialDesign Icons from react native vector icons in the same file, how should I import it?

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
```

(and)

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

in the same file

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After going through the original source files I found out that the icons was exported like

```
export default iconSet
```

So you could just use any arbitrary name to import.

In that case, the final code will look like this:

```
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons;
import Ionicon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Thank You Fran Rios

Comment: can you please tell me  after this code  how to import Icon  ?

Comment: and from where ? got stuck in missign fonts using this.

Comment: why you didnt mark Fran Rios`s answer as correct answer?

Answer (score 13):

You can take advantage of using the name you want on each import due type of exporting on `react-native-vector-icons`:

```
import IonIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
```

Then you can user IonIcon and MaterialIcon respectively in your code.

Comment: This did not work for me: I got Unexpected token error in the import line. Any ideas?

Comment: import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'; works

Comment: No need for "as" keyword to rename default exports. You give it the whatever name you want. The "as" keyword is used for renaming non default exports, i.e. import {icon as myIcon} from...

Comment: Totally true, it's more elegant the way you suggested.

Answer (score 11):

also, you can use it:

// icons.js

```
import MaterialCommunityIconsI from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import SimpleLineIconsI from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons'
import MaterialIconsI from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import FontAwesomeI from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import FoundationI from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation'
import EvilIconsI from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import OcticonsI from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons'
import IoniconsI from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import FeatherI from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather'
import EntypoI from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo'
import ZocialI from 'react-native-vector-icons/Zocial'
import React from 'react'

export const MaterialCommunityIcons = props => (
    <MaterialCommunityIconsI {...props} />
)
 const SimpleLineIcons = props => <SimpleLineIconsI {...props} />
 const MaterialIcons = props => <MaterialIconsI {...props} />
 const FontAwesome = props => <FontAwesomeI {...props} />
 const Foundation = props => <FoundationI {...props} />
 const EvilIcons = props => <EvilIconsI {...props} />
 const Ionicons = props => <IoniconsI {...props} />
 const Octicons = props => <OcticonsI {...props} />
 const Feather = props => <FeatherI {...props} />
 const Entypo = props => <EntypoI {...props} />
 const Zocial = props => <ZocialI {...props} />

export default  {
    MaterialCommunityIcons,
    SimpleLineIcons,
    SimpleLineIcons,
    MaterialIcons,
    FontAwesome,
    Foundation,
    EvilIcons,
    Ionicons,
    Octicons,
    Feather,
    Entypo,
    Zocial 
}
```

and you can everytime use it from components:

```
import Icon  from '../../styles/icons'; 


<Icon.FontAwesome name="user" size={22} style={styles.iconNav} />
```

Comment: This is good. allows the good use of components in the application and also a simple solution.

Comment: You don't need to export MaterialCommunityIcons alone. Really helpful.

Comment: @JasurKurbanov sure

Answer (score 2):

1- Create file Icon.js.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import Ionicon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import ZocialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Zocial';
import EntypoIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';
import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import FAIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import OcticonIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
import FAIcon5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import FoundationIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import SimpleLineIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import MaterialCommunityIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const getIcon = type => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'fontisto':
      return Fontisto;
    case 'material':
      return MaterialIcon;
    case 'evil':
      return EvilIcon;
    case 'feather':
      return Feather;
    case 'ant':
      return AntDesign;
    case 'simpleLine':
      return SimpleLineIcon;
    case 'zocial':
      return ZocialIcon;
    case 'simpleLine':
      return SimpleLineIcon;
    case 'foundation':
      return FoundationIcon;
    case 'fa5':
      return FAIcon5;
    case 'fa':
      return FAIcon;
    case 'ionicon':
      return Ionicon;
    case 'materialCommunity':
      return MaterialCommunityIcon;
    case 'entypo':
      return EntypoIcon;
    case 'octicon':
      return OcticonIcon;
    default:
      return FAIcon;
  }
};

const Icon = ({
  type,
  ...props
}) => {
  const FontIcon = getIcon(type);

  return <FontIcon { ...props
  }
  />;
};

export default Icon;
```

2- After Import the Icon file:

```
import Icon from '../../component/common/Icon';
```

3- And use like that:

```
<Icon type ="fontisto" name="player-settings" />,
```

Answer (score 0):

Had Fiddled with the same idea

There is the workaround I had created for the solution with the simplest Implementation & Usage

---

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { TextProps } from 'react-native';
import IconEntypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import IconEvilIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import IconFeather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import IconFontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import IconFontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import IconFoundation from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation';
import IconIonicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import IconMaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import IconMaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import IconOcticons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
import IconZocial from 'react-native-vector-icons/Zocial';
import IconSimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import IconAntDesignIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

export const IconSets = {
    Entypo: 'Entypo',
    EvilIcons: 'EvilIcons',
    Feather: 'Feather',
    FontAwesome: 'FontAwesome',
    FontAwesome5: 'FontAwesome5',
    Foundation: 'Foundation',
    Ionicons: 'Ionicons',
    MaterialIcons: 'MaterialIcons',
    MaterialCommunityIcons: 'MaterialCommunityIcons',
    Octicons: 'Octicons',
    Zocial: 'Zocial',
    SimpleLineIcons: 'SimpleLineIcons',
    AntDesign: 'AntDesign',
};

type Props = {
    iconSet: string;
    name: string;
    size: number;
    color: string;
};

const Icons = (props: Props) => {
    const { iconSet, ...otherProps } = props;
    switch (iconSet) {
        case IconSets.Entypo:
            return <IconEntypo {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.EvilIcons:
            return <IconEvilIcons {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.Feather:
            return <IconFeather {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.FontAwesome:
            return <IconFontAwesome {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.FontAwesome5:
            return <IconFontAwesome5 {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.Foundation:
            return <IconFoundation {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.Ionicons:
            return <IconIonicons {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.MaterialIcons:
            return <IconMaterialIcons {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.MaterialCommunityIcons:
            return <IconMaterialCommunityIcons {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.Octicons:
            return <IconOcticons {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.Zocial:
            return <IconZocial {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.SimpleLineIcons:
            return <IconSimpleLineIcons {...otherProps} />;
        case IconSets.AntDesign:
            return <IconAntDesignIcons {...otherProps} />;
        default:
            return <IconFontAwesome {...otherProps} />;
    }
};

export default memo(Icons);
```

---

Here's a snippet of Usage:

```
<Icons iconSet={IconSets.FontAwesome} name={"rocket"}></Icons>
```

---

Additionally, You can comment out the unused ones for optimizations.